# Count duplicates in a 2D Array and create a new 2D Array and expand it with the counts

Tags: javascript

I have a 2d this array with few values. I want to count the duplicates in this array and get a new 2d array with the values and in the end the number of counts

```js
let colors = [
  ['blue', 'green', 5.00, 57],
  ['blue', 'green', 5.00, 57],
  ['yellow', 'green', 8.30, 84],
  ['blue', 'green', 5.00, 57],
  ['orange', 'blue', 7.00, 0],
  ['yellow', 'green', 8.30, 84],
];

function count_duplicate() {
  let counts = []
  for (let i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    if (counts[colors[i]]) {
      counts[colors[i]] += 1
    } else {
      counts[colors[i]] = 1
    }
  }
  console.log(counts);
}

count_duplicate();
```

now ich have this result

```
counts = [blue,green,5,57: 3, yellow,green,8.3,84: 2, orange,blue,7,0: 1]
```

but i need the array like this

```
counts = [[blue,green,5,57,3],
          [yellow,green,8.3,84,2],
          [orange,blue,7,0,1]]
```

Comment: If you check the browser console after running the snippet it shows up there too, its just the limited snippet console that doesn't handle it. (array.length is still 0 of course.)

Comment: Chrome does but FF doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change from `array []` to `an object {}`, to easly manipulate each `sub-array(row)` how many times occures, it should be an object not an array!
and Using `Object.entries` looping through its *`key(str) and value(times)`*, and return `str` splitted by *comma* and their *times of occurences*.

```js
let colors = [
  ["blue", "green", 5.0, 57],
  ["blue", "green", 5.0, 57],
  ["yellow", "green", 8.3, 84],
  ["blue", "green", 5.0, 57],
  ["orange", "blue", 7.0, 0],
  ["yellow", "green", 8.3, 84],
];

function count_duplicate() {
  let counts = {};//<-- 
  for (let i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    if (counts[colors[i]]) {
      counts[colors[i]] += 1;
    } else {
      counts[colors[i]] = 1;
    }
  }
 console.log(counts); //{ 'blue,green,5,57': 3, 'yellow,green,8.3,84': 2, 'orange,blue,7,0': 1 }
  const res = Object.entries(counts).map((count) => {
    [str, times] = count; //['blue,green,5,57': 3]
    return [...str.split(","), times];//[ 'blue', 'green', '5', '57', 3 ]
  });
  console.log(res);
}
count_duplicate();
```

***Result:***

```js
[ [ 'blue', 'green', '5', '57', 3 ],
  [ 'yellow', 'green', '8.3', '84', 2 ],
  [ 'orange', 'blue', '7', '0', 1 ] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) here to achieve the result:

```js
let colors = [
  ["blue", "green", 5.0, 57],
  ["blue", "green", 5.0, 57],
  ["yellow", "green", 8.3, 84],
  ["blue", "green", 5.0, 57],
  ["orange", "blue", 7.0, 0],
  ["yellow", "green", 8.3, 84],
];

function count_duplicate() {
  let counts = new Map();

  for (let i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    const data = counts.get(colors[i].toString());
    if (data) data.count++;
    else counts.set(colors[i].toString(), { value: colors[i], count: 1 });
  }

  const result = [];
  for (let [, { value, count }] of counts) {
    result.push([...value, count]);
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(count_duplicate());
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about fancy syntax but using a hashmap should work which is just a JavaScript object.

```js
let colors = [
        ['blue', 'green', 5.00, 57],
        ['blue', 'green', 5.00, 57],
        ['yellow', 'green', 8.30, 84],
        ['blue', 'green', 5.00, 57],
        ['orange', 'blue', 7.00, 0],
        ['yellow', 'green', 8.30, 84],
       
];

const hashmap = {};

colors.forEach(color => {
    const key = JSON.stringify(color);
    if(!hashmap[key]) hashmap[key] = 1;
    else hashmap[key]++;
    if(hashmap[key] == 1) return color;
});

console.log(hashmap);

const uniqueArray = [];

for(const key in hashmap) 
    uniqueArray.push(JSON.parse(key));

console.log(uniqueArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that output because the environment you're using is automatically coercing the array to a string. For example, Chrome and NodeJS do this, Firefox doesn't.

Here's a simple approach that uses an object to store data the updated color information in key/value pairs. It uses [`toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString) on the array for the key, and an array as the value comprising the original array, and an initialised total. The output (all the arrays stored as property values in the object) can then be extracted with [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values).

```js
let colors=[["blue","green",5,57],["blue","green",5,57],["yellow","green",8.3,84],["blue","green",5,57],["orange","blue",7,0],["yellow","green",8.3,84]];

const out = {};

colors.forEach(arr => {

  // Create the key from the stringified array
  const key = arr.toString();

  // If the output object doesn't have a
  // property with that key create one with
  // an array built from the array, and setting
  // the total to zero
  out[key] = out[key] ?? [ ...arr, 0 ];

  // Increment the total (the last element)
  out[key][arr.length]++;

});

// Use Object.values to retrieve
// the updated arrays
console.log(Object.values(out));
```

Additional documentation

- [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)
- [`Nullish coalescing operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)