# Get count of duplicates based on two columns in a multidivisional array and add count to the array Google Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to count the duplicates in an array based on the conditions

```
values[i][2]==values[i+1][2] && values[i][1]==values[i+1][1])
```

and add the duplicate value to the column `Total Gifts`

And sum the totals for `ig_Flow` and output the results to the column `Total Flow`

I have trid modifing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70012763/count-duplicates-in-a-2d-array-and-create-a-new-2d-array-and-expand-it-with-the) but with no sucess

```
function count_duplicate() {
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Have");
  let values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  let counts = new Map();

  for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    const data = counts.get(values[i].toString());
    if (data) data.count++;
    else counts.set(values[i].toString(), { value: values[i], count: 1 });
  }

  const result = [];
  for (let [, { value, count }] of counts) {
    result.push([...value, count]);
  }
  console.log(result);
  return result;
}
```

Here is a Google sheet with data
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Xg0iSSTkJydkIm1UnlZVMQ48ACcezx1720ot8_hJ2c0/edit?usp=sharing

Have
[image]

values=

```
[ [ 'Id',
    'From',
    'To',
    'ig_Transaction',
    'ig_Flow',
    'ig_Running Balance',
    'Description',
    'ig_Date',
    'Type',
    'Total Gifts',
    'Total Flow' ],
  [ 'conn-1',
    'Alan',
    'Alícia',
    'Giving',
    1,
    60,
    'Stuff',
    '20/10/2022',
    'Person',
    '',
    '' ],
  [ 'conn-2',
    'Alan',
    'Ashish',
    'Giving',
    2,
    62,
    'Stuff',
    '26/10/2022',
    'Person',
    '',
    '' ],
  [ 'conn-3',
    'Alan',
    'Ashish',
    'Giving',
    3,
    59,
    'Stuff',
    '26/11/2022',
    'Person',
    '',
    '' ],
  [ 'conn-4',
    'Alan',
    'Deborah',
    'Giving',
    15,
    48,
    'Stuff',
    '26/10/2022',
    'Person',
    '',
    '' ],
  [ 'conn-5',
    'Christine',
    'Deborah',
    'Giving',
    1,
    47,
    'Stuff',
    '26/10/2022',
    'Person',
    '',
    '' ],
  [ 'conn-6',
    'Christine',
    'Deborah',
    'Giving',
    4,
    61,
    'Stuff',
    '26/10/2022',
    'Person',
    '',
    '' ],
  [ 'conn-7',
    'Christine',
    'Deborah',
    'Giving',
    4,
    61,
    'Stuff',
    '26/10/2023',
    'Person',
    '',
    '' ],
  [ 'conn-7',
    'Christine',
    'Gitanjali',
    'Giving',
    1,
    54,
    'Stuff',
    '26/10/2022',
    'Person',
    '',
    '' ],
  [ 'conn-8',
    'Christine',
    'Jacklina',
    'Giving',
    7,
    43,
    'Stuff',
    '26/10/2022',
    'Person',
    '',
    '' ],
  [ 'conn-9',
    'Jane',
    'Ashish',
    'Giving',
    1,
    55,
    'Stuff',
    '26/10/2022',
    'Person',
    '',
    '' ],
  [ 'conn-10',
    'Jane',
    'Ashish',
    'Giving',
    1,
    58,
    'Stuff',
    '24/10/2022',
    'Person',
    '',
    '' ],
  [ 'conn-11',
    'Jane',
    'Ashish',
    'Giving',
    5,
    22,
    'Stuff',
    '26/10/2022',
    'Person',
    '',
    '' ],
  [ 'conn-12',
    'Jane',
    'Ashish',
    'Giving',
    5,
    10,
    'Stuff',
    '19/10/2022',
    'Person',
    '',
    '' ] ]
```

Need
[image]

values=

```
[ [ 'Id',
    'From',
    'To',
    'ig_Transaction',
    'ig_Flow',
    'ig_Running Balance',
    'Description',
    'ig_Date',
    'Type',
    'Total Gifts',
    'Total Flow' ],
  [ 'conn-1',
    'Alan',
    'Alícia',
    'Giving',
    1,
    60,
    'Stuff',
    '20/10/2022',
    'Person',
    1,
    1 ],
  [ 'conn-2',
    'Alan',
    'Ashish',
    'Giving',
    2,
    62,
    'Stuff',
    '26/10/2022',
    'Person',
    2,
    5 ],
  [ 'conn-3',
    'Alan',
    'Ashish',
    'Giving',
    3,
    59,
    'Stuff',
    '26/11/2022',
    'Person',
    2,
    5 ],
  [ 'conn-4',
    'Alan',
    'Deborah',
    'Giving',
    15,
    48,
    'Stuff',
    '26/10/2022',
    'Person',
    1,
    15 ],
  [ 'conn-5',
    'Christine',
    'Deborah',
    'Giving',
    1,
    47,
    'Stuff',
    '26/10/2022',
    'Person',
    3,
    9 ],
  [ 'conn-6',
    'Christine',
    'Deborah',
    'Giving',
    4,
    61,
    'Stuff',
    '26/10/2022',
    'Person',
    3,
    9 ],
  [ 'conn-7',
    'Christine',
    'Deborah',
    'Giving',
    4,
    61,
    'Stuff',
    '26/10/2023',
    'Person',
    3,
    9 ],
  [ 'conn-7',
    'Christine',
    'Gitanjali',
    'Giving',
    1,
    54,
    'Stuff',
    '26/10/2022',
    'Person',
    1,
    1 ],
  [ 'conn-8',
    'Christine',
    'Jacklina',
    'Giving',
    7,
    43,
    'Stuff',
    '26/10/2022',
    'Person',
    1,
    7 ],
  [ 'conn-9',
    'Jane',
    'Ashish',
    'Giving',
    1,
    55,
    'Stuff',
    '26/10/2022',
    'Person',
    4,
    11 ],
  [ 'conn-10',
    'Jane',
    'Ashish',
    'Giving',
    1,
    58,
    'Stuff',
    '24/10/2022',
    'Person',
    4,
    11 ],
  [ 'conn-11',
    'Jane',
    'Ashish',
    'Giving',
    5,
    22,
    'Stuff',
    '26/10/2022',
    'Person',
    4,
    11 ],
  [ 'conn-12',
    'Jane',
    'Ashish',
    'Giving',
    5,
    10,
    'Stuff',
    '19/10/2022',
    'Person',
    4,
    11 ] ]
```

Thanks for assistance

Comment: your "have" sheet has 13 items and your "need" sheet has 14.  Is that accurate?

Comment: sigh, No, I will fix that. Apologies

Comment: I fixed the Have Image and updated the Have values

Comment: is there a reason you're doing it in javascript instead of just a simple SUMIFS() and COUNTIFS()? see, e.g. new tab mk_help

Comment: No, that just looked promising. Also, this is just a step in a longed process so I need it to work on an array not at the sheet level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count Duplicates and Total

```
function count_duplicate() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const osh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  osh.clearContents();
  const vs1 = sh1.getRange(2, 1, sh1.getLastRow() - 1, sh1.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  let sObj = { pA: [] };
  vs1.forEach((r, i) => {
    if (vs1[i + 1] && r[1] == vs1[i + 1][1] && r[2] == vs1[i + 1][2]) {
      let p = r[1] + "/" + r[2];
      if (!sObj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
        sObj[p] = { counts: 1, ttl: r[4] }
        sObj.pA.push(p);
      } else {
        sObj[p].counts += 1;
        sObj[p].ttl += r[4];
      }
    } else {
      let p = r[1] + "/" + r[2]
      if (!sObj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
        sObj[p] = { counts: 0, ttl: r[4] };
        sObj.pA.push(p);
      } else {
        sObj[p].counts += 1;
        sObj[p].ttl += r[4]
      }
    }
  })
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(sObj));
  let arr = [["From","To","Total","Count"]]
  sObj.pA.forEach(p => {
    let t = p.split('/')
    arr.push([t[0],t[1],sObj[p].ttl,sObj[p].counts])
  })
  if(arr.length > 1) {
    osh.getRange(1,1,arr.length,arr[0].length).setValues(arr)
  }
}

Execution log
3:28:06 PM  Notice  Execution started
3:28:06 PM  Info    {"pA":["Alan/Alícia","Alan/Ashish","Alan/Deborah","Christine/Deborah","Christine/Gitanjali","Christine/Jacklina","Jane/Ashish"],"Alan/Alícia":{"counts":0,"ttl":1},"Alan/Ashish":{"counts":2,"ttl":5},"Alan/Deborah":{"counts":0,"ttl":15},"Christine/Deborah":{"counts":3,"ttl":9},"Christine/Gitanjali":{"counts":0,"ttl":1},"Christine/Jacklina":{"counts":0,"ttl":7},"Jane/Ashish":{"counts":4,"ttl":12}}
3:28:09 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Data:

| Id | From | To | ig_Transaction | ig_Flow | ig_Running Balance | Description | ig_Date | Type | Total Gifts | Total Flow |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| conn-1 | Alan | Alícia | Giving | 1 | 60 | Stuff | 20/10/2022 | Person |  |  |
| conn-2 | Alan | Ashish | Giving | 2 | 62 | Stuff | 26/10/2022 | Person |  |  |
| conn-3 | Alan | Ashish | Giving | 3 | 59 | Stuff | 26/11/2022 | Person |  |  |
| conn-4 | Alan | Deborah | Giving | 15 | 48 | Stuff | 26/10/2022 | Person |  |  |
| conn-5 | Christine | Deborah | Giving | 1 | 47 | Stuff | 26/10/2022 | Person |  |  |
| conn-6 | Christine | Deborah | Giving | 4 | 61 | Stuff | 26/10/2022 | Person |  |  |
| conn-7 | Christine | Deborah | Giving | 4 | 61 | Stuff | 26/10/2023 | Person |  |  |
| conn-7 | Christine | Gitanjali | Giving | 1 | 54 | Stuff | 26/10/2022 | Person |  |  |
| conn-8 | Christine | Jacklina | Giving | 7 | 43 | Stuff | 26/10/2022 | Person |  |  |
| conn-9 | Jane | Ashish | Giving | 1 | 55 | Stuff | 26/10/2022 | Person |  |  |
| conn-10 | Jane | Ashish | Giving | 1 | 58 | Stuff | 24/10/2022 | Person |  |  |
| conn-11 | Jane | Ashish | Giving | 5 | 22 | Stuff | 26/10/2022 | Person |  |  |
| conn-12 | Jane | Ashish | Giving | 5 | 10 | Stuff | 19/10/2022 | Person |  |  |

Output:

| From | To | Total | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alan | Alícia | 1 | 0 |
| Alan | Ashish | 5 | 2 |
| Alan | Deborah | 15 | 0 |
| Christine | Deborah | 9 | 3 |
| Christine | Gitanjali | 1 | 0 |
| Christine | Jacklina | 7 | 0 |
| Jane | Ashish | 12 | 4 |

Comment: wow, thanks for that :) with a little study, I should be able to figure out what you did